# When do I need to add @Composable with Android Studio Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

The following code is from the [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/AdvancedStateAndSideEffectsCodelab).

I find that `fun MainScreen()` add `@Composable`, and `fun launchDetailsActivity` doesn't add `@Composable`.

It make me confused. I think all function which apply to Compose should to add `@Composable`, why doesn't `fun launchDetailsActivity` add @Composable?

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        setContent {
            ProvideWindowInsets {
                ProvideImageLoader {
                    CraneTheme {
                        MainScreen(
                            onExploreItemClicked = { launchDetailsActivity(context = this, item = it) }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun MainScreen(onExploreItemClicked: OnExploreItemClicked) {
  ...
}


fun launchDetailsActivity(context: Context, item: ExploreModel) {
    context.startActivity(createDetailsActivityIntent(context, item))
}
```

Comment: i think this is generated by navigation?

Comment: From what i know a composable function should be started with uppercase letter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function with @Composable is not just a function it tells the compose compiler that this is a UI element. Take this data and build a Widget with it.

So you have to determine when you will add @Composable based on whether this function draws something in the UI or not. In the non compose world you can think of this function like a View.

For example, this function takes a parameter name and builds a Text widget with the text "Hello $name" which you can see in the UI.

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text("Hello $name")
}
```

But

```
fun getName(firstName: String, lastName: String): String {
    return "$firstName $lastName"
}
```

This function is not a composable function. It is not annotated with @Composable because it is not a widget, it shouldn't render anything in the UI. It just takes two parameters, Concatenates them, and returns the String.

In your case, MainScreen is the function that is rendering the Main screen of your app so it is a UI element. But function launchDetailsActivity doesn't draw anything in the UI. It just navigates from one activity to another activity.

Few things to remember:

Function with @Composable doesn't return anything.

You can't call a composable function from a non-composable function.

Unlike non-composable function composable function start with an Uppercase letter.

You can read this doc for details https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark view builder functions with `@Composable`, to be **directly** called from an other `@Composable`.

If you have a side effect function, it shouldn't be called **directly** from composable. It can be called from touch handlers, like click in your example, or using a side effect, like `LaunchedEffect`. Check out more about what's side effect in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SomeView() {
    // this is directly called from view builder and should be marked with @Composable
    OtherView()

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        // LaunchedEffect a side effect function, and as it's called 
        // from LaunchedEffect it can be a suspend fun (optionally)
        handleLaunchedEffect()
    }
    Button(onClick = { handleButtonClick() }) { // or onClick = ::handleButtonClick

    }
}

@Composable
fun OtherView() {

}

suspend fun handleLaunchedEffect() {

}

fun handleButtonClick() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Composable` if you are using calling another function annotated with  `@Composable` that's it pretty simple.

Generally all `@Composable` functions starts with uppercase letter but some also start with lowercase like everything that starts with `remember`

So when you are using these functions inside another function you need to use `@Composable` else even android studio will yell at you because composable function can be invoked from another composable.

Comment: Thanks! but why doesn't `fun launchDetailsActivity` add `@Composable?`?  You know that `fun MainScreen`  which has added `@Composable`  invoke it

Comment: Hey it's the other way around

Comment: Let's say our function name is `test` if `test` calls `MainScreen` it needs to be annotated with `@Composable` but if `MainScreen` calls `test()` we don't need to do anything it will be treated as normal function